# Error migrating wordpress theme to aws lightsail

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, migration, wordpress-theming

I did a migration of a site to aws lighsail, when testing it locally and lifting it using xammp it works without problem and everything is displayed correctly, but when uploading it and although the theme is selected it only shows me a message that says **Hello world! Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!**

Check and change the permissions of the folder but I still get the same. I am going to share what appears to me in each of the environments.

**Site on local**
[image]

**Site in aws lightsail**
[image]

The files are exactly the same and I upload them using filezilla

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Solution 1/2: remove/purge all caches and disable all cache plugins.

Solution 2/2: ctrl+shift+del and remove all caches.

That's all.